is a cell boldface
I'm looking for a function to determine if a cell is formatted bold. I'm using LibreOffice Calc, and for ease of use, I have a range of items to buy and their prices. I want to have a simple method of marking an item as being bought. Rather than highlight the cell, hit F2, Home, and *, e.g., I'd like to be able to just highlight a cell (or range) and hit Ctrl-B. But I'm not locating a function to do this.  I appreciate your help.

Write a macros, assign a shortcut? 1. https://books.libreoffice.org/en/GS70/GS7013-GettingStartedWithMacros.html 2. https://books.libreoffice.org/en/GS70/GS7013-GettingStartedWithMacros.html#toc28

Me, I'd create a hidden column and use a marker such as the word "Bought" to indicate something's state. I'd then use Conditional Formatting to make the appropriate row of cells bold. You can then query the hidden status cell rather than the formatting

But because that ^^ is not answering your question as asked I can't put it as an answer
